# DebuggerVisualizer debugging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, debuggervisualizer

I am working on a collection debugger visualizer in VS2010 using C# and I cannot find a way to debug the visualizer itself (not the client app). Can anyone give me some help regarding this? Basically I want to set some breakpoints in the debugger visualizer code at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a call to [Debugger.Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) at the location you want to set your breakpoint.

Additionally, you can create a test driver as explained in the MSDN documentation: [How to: Test and Debug a Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164761.aspx)

Comment: Inserting Debbugger.Break() caused VS not to respond anymore, I am able to work with the link you sent. Thanks.